# Trouble with Mongoose and Schema.Types.Mixed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to have a completely mixed model but cant really get it to work, here is the complete javascript:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    async = require('async');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/whatever');

var SomeDocument = mongoose.model('SomeDocument', new Schema({ any: Schema.Types.Mixed }) );

var AnotherDocument = mongoose.model('AnotherDocument', new Schema({ any: Schema.Types.Mixed }, { strict: false } ) );

async.waterfall([
    function(cb) {
        var saveThis = {lets: "have", some: "fun"};
        console.log("Trying to save:", saveThis);
        SomeDocument.create(saveThis, function(err, savedDoc) {
            console.log("Created SomeDocument: ", savedDoc);
            cb(null, savedDoc._id.toString());
        });
    },
    function(id, cb) {
        SomeDocument.findOne({_id: id}, function(err, someDoc) {
            console.log("Found SomeDocument", someDoc);
            cb(null);
        });
    },
    function(cb) {
        AnotherDocument.create({maybe: "now", we: "can", have: "fun"}, function(err, savedDoc) {
            console.log("Created AnotherDocument", savedDoc);
            cb(null, savedDoc._id.toString());
        });
    },
    function(id, cb) {
        AnotherDocument.findOne({_id: id}, function(err, anotherDoc) {
            console.log("Found AnotherDocument", anotherDoc);
            console.log("Seems like progress, but what about: ", anotherDoc._id, anotherDoc.maybe, anotherDoc.we, anotherDoc.have);
            console.log("need moar brains");
            cb(null);
        });
    },
    function(cb) {
        mongoose.disconnect();
    }
]);
```

Neither SomeDocument or AnotherDocument works as i would expect. The first one doesn't even save the extra fields, and the other wont let me read the objects properties...

The above code outputs:

```
$ node test.js
Trying to save: { lets: 'have', some: 'fun' }
Created SomeDocument:  { __v: 0, _id: 53be7279c90a4def0d000001 }
Found SomeDocument { _id: 53be7279c90a4def0d000001, __v: 0 }
Created AnotherDocument { __v: 0,
  maybe: 'now',
  we: 'can',
  have: 'fun',
  _id: 53be7279c90a4def0d000002 }
Found AnotherDocument { maybe: 'now',
  we: 'can',
  have: 'fun',
  _id: 53be7279c90a4def0d000002,
  __v: 0 }
Seems like progress, but what about:  53be7279c90a4def0d000002 undefined undefined undefined
need moar brains
```

Is this a bug or am i missing something?

The main issue is that even though console.log actually seems to output the document as it was saved, when i try to access `anotherDoc.maybe` - its suddenly `undefined`

Versions:

```
mongoose@3.6.20 node_modules/mongoose
├── regexp-clone@0.0.1
├── sliced@0.0.5
├── muri@0.3.1
├── hooks@0.2.1
├── mpath@0.1.1
├── ms@0.1.0
├── mpromise@0.2.1 (sliced@0.0.4)
└── mongodb@1.3.19 (kerberos@0.0.3, bson@0.2.2)

$ node -v
v0.10.25

$ uname -a
Linux deployment 3.11.0-24-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 4 21:19:31 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of "waterfall" is actually not correct. If you expect those variables to be visable in your final operation then you need to pass all of them through. So each successive callback needs to "pass on" the variables you received. These do not just "waterfall down" the the lowest level automatically.

On to the real problem here though.

If you just want a completely  schema-less approach then just use `{"strict": false }` only.

```
var docSchema = new Schema({},{ "strict": false });
var Document = mongoose.model( "Document", documentSchema );
```

That does not restrict the fields and basically everything works. "Mixed" is really only for field definitions that may vary in fields and types.

The default `_id` as ObjectId is kept in this case, but you don't seem to be overriding that otherwise.

---

Looking at the question again, the point of `"strict": false` was missed [from the documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict). The accessors for otherwise "defined" fields are not there. You need to use generic `.set()` and `.get()`:

```
var async = require("async"),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');


var mixSchema = new Schema({},{ "strict": false });

var Mix = mongoose.model( "Mix", mixSchema );

var report = function(label,data) {
  console.log(
    "%s\n%s\n",
    label,
    JSON.stringify( data, undefined, 4 )
  );
};

async.waterfall([

  function(callback) {
    Mix.create({ "lets": "have", "some": "fun" },function(err,doc) {
      if (err) throw err;
      report("Created",doc);
      callback(null,doc._id);
    });
  },

  function(id,callback) {
    Mix.findById(id,function(err,doc) {
      if (err) throw err;
      report("Found",doc);
      callback(null);
    });
  },

  function(callback) {
    Mix.create({
      "maybe": "now", "we": "can", "have": "fun"
    },function(err,doc) {
      if (err) throw err;
      report("Created",doc);
      callback(null,doc._id);
    });

  },

  function(id,callback) {
    Mix.findById(id,function(err,doc) {
      if (err) throw err;
      report("Found",doc);
      console.log(
        "But does not have built in accessors when strict:false. So...\n"
      );

      console.log(
        "\"maybe\": \"%s\" \"we\": \"%s\" \"have\": \"%s\"\n",
        doc.get("maybe"), doc.get("we"), doc.get("have")
      );

      // Or get raw values
      console.log("In the raw!\n");
      var raw = doc.toObject();
      for ( var k in raw ) {
        console.log( "\"%s\": \"%s\"", k, raw[k] );
      }

      console.log("\nAnd again\n");
      console.log(
        "\"maybe\": \"%s\" \"we\": \"%s\" \"have\": \"%s\"\n",
        raw.maybe, raw.we, raw.have
      );

      callback();
    });
  },

],function(err) {
  console.log("done");
  process.exit();
});
```

As stated before, the `_id` accessor still exists is it is there by default unless again your turn this off. For the others though you use the `.get()` method. Updating typically is not so much of a problem if you are generally using the MongoDB [update operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/). But with any JavaScript code manipulation on mongoose objects you must call `.set()`.

Output:

```
Created
{
    "__v": 0,
    "lets": "have",
    "some": "fun",
    "_id": "53bf6f09ac1add4b3b2386b9"
}

Found
{
    "_id": "53bf6f09ac1add4b3b2386b9",
    "lets": "have",
    "some": "fun",
    "__v": 0 
}

Created
{
    "__v": 0,
    "maybe": "now",
    "we": "can",
    "have": "fun",
    "_id": "53bf6f09ac1add4b3b2386ba"
}

Found
{
    "_id": "53bf6f09ac1add4b3b2386ba",
    "maybe": "now",
    "we": "can",
    "have": "fun",
    "__v": 0
}

But does not have built in accessors when strict:false. So...

"maybe": "now" "we": "can" "have": "fun"

In the raw!

"_id": "53bf6f09ac1add4b3b2386ba"
"maybe": "now"
"we": "can"
"have": "fun"
"__v": "0"

And again

"maybe": "now" "we": "can" "have": "fun"

done
```

Comment: Im still unable to access the objects properties,
           console.log("Seems like progress, but what about: ", anotherDoc._id, anotherDoc.maybe, anotherDoc.we, anotherDoc.have);

anotherDoc.maybe is undefined

Comment: @fasmide I was mainly describing what you "should" be doing as your "Mixed" interpretation is incorrect. Also your "waterfall" processing interpretation is incorrect which is the cause of this. I described that as well now for good measure.

Comment: Your right about the waterfall i know that, i just use it here to have some control structure. (And i dont need the variables in the lower levels anyway - just the id so i can try to lookup what got saved) The javascript is just made as a prototype so i could try to figure out whats wrong with the `anotherDoc` that i fetch right after it gets saved.

Comment: @fasmide Give me a moment and I'll post through some code that works.

Comment: @fasmide Eventually got back with a sample and some explanation.

Comment: Ahh, i guess i didn't have the imagination to think they would make the properties inaccessible. (Then you would have to know if the model your working with is strict or not, and then choose to `.get` or direct access them - it gets even more ugly if you had a lot of code and one of your models goes `strict:false` for whatever reason) My example works just fine when adding `.toObject()` or using `.get`, but i didnt know about theise, Thanks :)